# Error when loading data using web.DataReader, yahoo finance

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I try to load data using web.DataReader but I always get the error "RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: [https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FB/history?period1=1325390400&period2=1577937599&interval=1d&frequency=1d&filter=history"](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FB/history?period1=1325390400&period2=1577937599&interval=1d&frequency=1d&filter=history%22).

I already used the following package updates and my code worked fine yesterday. However today I still get the same error as before (i.e., unable to read URL).

```
!pip install --upgrade pandas
!pip install --upgrade pandas-datareader
```

PS: I use Google Colab

Here is the full beginning of my code (including the error):

```
!pib install numpy
!pib install matplotlib
!pib install pandas
!pip install --upgrade pandas
!pip install --upgrade pandas-datareader
```

```
 # Importing packages
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as web
import datetime as dt
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler #package used in order to scale the data
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM
```

```
# Load Data 
company = 'FB' #picking the company we want to study

start=dt.datetime(2012,1,1) # picking the dataframe we are interested in 
end=dt.datetime(2020,1,1)
```

```
data = web.DataReader(company, 'yahoo',start,end)
```

RemoteDataError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 data = web.DataReader(company, 'yahoo',start,end)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py in _get_response(self, url, params, headers)
179             msg += "\nResponse Text:\n{0}".format(last_response_text)
180
--> 181         raise RemoteDataError(msg)
182
183     def _get_crumb(self, *args):

RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FB/history?period1=1325390400&period2=1577937599&interval=1d&frequency=1d&filter=history
Response Text:
b'\n  \n  \n      \n      Yahoo\n      \n      \n      \n  html {\n      height: 100%;\n  }\n  body {\n      background: #fafafc url(https://s.yimg.com/nn/img/sad-panda-201402200631.png) 50% 50%;\n      background-size: cover;\n      height: 100%;\n      text-align: center;\n      font: 300 18px "helvetica neue", helvetica, verdana, tahoma, arial, sans-serif;\n  }\n  table {\n      height: 100%;\n      width: 100%;\n      table-layout: fixed;\n      border-collapse: collapse;\n      border-spacing: 0;\n      border: none;\n  }\n  h1 {\n      font-size: 42px;\n      font-weight: 400;\n      color: #400090;\n  }\n  p {\n      color: #1A1A1A;\n  }\n  #message-1 {\n      font-weight: bold;\n      margin: 0;\n  }\n  #message-2 {\n      display: inline-block;\n      *display: inline;\n      zoom: 1;\n      max-width: 17em;\n      _width: 17em;\n  }\n      \n  \n    document.write('&test=\'+encodeURIComponent(\'%\')+\'" width="0px" height="0px"/>');var beacon = new Image();beacon.src="//bcn.fp.yahoo.com/p?s=1197757129&t="+ne...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone faces the same issue as mine, I just found out how to solve it!

Adapt this piece of code in your notebook:

```
start=dt.datetime(2010,1,1)
end=dt.datetime(2017,1,1)
df = yf.download(tickers=['^GSPC'], start=start, end=end)
```

Comment: "!pip install yfinance" & "import yfinance as yf" to get the package